# How to convert a code block to a string

Tags: ruby

I'd like write a method that returns the source code of any block passed to it as a string, e.g.:

```
=> block_to_string { foo(42) }
=> "foo(42)"
```

It would be easy if the block were already a string, e.g.:

```
block_to_string { "foo(42)" }
```

but then, I'd miss syntax highlighting, etc., for that block. So how can I write `block_to_string`?

```
def block_to_string
  # what goes here?
end
```

Comment: How do you define `eval_code_on`?

Comment: You could maybe use https://github.com/cout/ruby-decompiler . Can't check now if it works with `Proc` or only with `Method`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it but I guess the sourcify gem is what you need: https://github.com/ngty/sourcify

```
lambda { x + y }.to_source(:strip_enclosure => true)
# >> "(x + y)"
```

Comment: This gem is like 9 years old, unsupported, and has warnings of bugginess beyond Ruby 1.9.